# Making the CKEditor 5 inline placeholder widget editable

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I've added the [placeholder widget](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/tutorials/implementing-an-inline-widget.html) to my CKEditor 5 build. However I don't like that I can't change the text after it is inserted. I tried removing `isObject` from the schema but that didn't do anything. I'd appreciate it if someone could show me how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 4 the edit of the text is done via popup called by double clicking on the placeholder:  https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/placeholder

In version 5 the placeholder was not fully implemented intentionally
"We didn't decide, though to implement a ready-to-use placeholder feature as it's usually needed to work differently in various systems"
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/871

So the only thing you can do is to implement the function you are missing yourself. I suggest looking at how version 4 does and understanding if it is applicable to version 5.

Comment: Thanks, i'd like to be able to edit the text in the editor, similar to how you can change the text inside a strong tag. I'm going to look at how that plugin is implemented to get an idea of how to do this.

Comment: @nfplee, were you able to achieve how to change the text inside the placeholder after it is added?

Comment: @VenkateshwaranSelvaraj I decided to simply insert my placeholder as text. Therefore I removed the schema stuff (in the editing.js file) and simply say the following in the command.js change event `writer.insertText(\`{{ ${value} }}\`, editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition());`.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it just with additional HTML block and control it with state (in my case I'm using React).

```
const CKInlineEditorField = ({
    defaultValue = '',
    onChange,
    placeholder = '',
}) => {
    const [showPlaceholder, setShowPlaceholder] = useState(false);
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!defaultValue) {
            setShowPlaceholder(true);
        }
    }, [defaultValue]);
    return (
        <div>
            <Paper variant="outlined" className="InlineEditor">
                <div className="InlineEditor__placeholder">
                    {showPlaceholder && `${t(placeholder)}...`}
                </div>
                <div className="InlineEditor__editor">
                    <CKEditor
                        editor={InlineEditor}
                        data={defaultValue}
                        onChange={(event, editor) => {
                            const data = editor.getData();
                            setShowPlaceholder(!data);
                        }}
                        onBlur={(event, editor) => {
                            const data = editor.getData();
                            onChange(data);
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
            </Paper>
        </div>
    );
};
```

And SCSS file:

```
.InlineEditor {
    background-color: #eee;
    position: relative;

    &__placeholder {
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        left: 10px;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    &__editor {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }
}
```